# Discord music bot cutting off music at random times

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, ytdl

I'm trying to make a music bot, i only started yesterday (with the voice side of discord.js, but i've been coding a normal bot for much longer) so i'm really new with voice and i don't know if i'm missing something simple, but anyway i made this code:

```
var voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("You have to join a voice channel!")

        voiceChannel.join()
        console.log(`joined channel: ${message.channel.name}`);

        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;

        }

        const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

        if (!video) return message.channel.send("The video you searched wasn't found!")

        voiceChannel.join().then(async connection => {

            const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
            const dispatcher = await connection.play(stream, streamOptions)

            dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                console.log('audio is now playing!');
            });
            
            dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
                console.log('audio has finished playing!');
            });

            dispatcher.on('error', console.error);

            const videoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setDescription(`Now playing: [${video.title}](${video.url})`)
                .addFields(

                    { name: 'Author:', value: `${video.author.name}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Duration:', value: `${video.timestamp}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Released:', value: `${video.ago}`, inline: true },

                )
                .setImage(video.image)
                .setFooter(`Total views: ${video.views}`)
                .setTimestamp()

            message.channel.send(videoEmbed)
```

It simply searches a video on youtube (with ytdl-core and ytdl-search), but the audio cutts off at random times, here's the error that it gives:
[image]

I think the wrong part might be `const dispatcher = await connection.play(stream, streamOptions)` but i'm not sure.

Comment: You're trying to join the voice channel twice, but I don't think that's what the issue. Is your internet connection staying stable throughout? If it drops at all you can encounter that error

Comment: My connection should be good enough, i'm also using my testing bot but i will add the music features on my main bot that is hosted on heroku when i got everything ready, so it should work better. Anyway i made some changes to the code, like i made a `const connection = ` instead of `voiceChannel.join().then(async connection => // ...`, and i remove dispatcher.on('finish')